# radio button to enable form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form containing two radio buttons, I want to enable corresponding fields when a radio button is checked. My code just isn't working, here it is:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $type = $('select'),
        $field1 = $("#fieldID1"),
        $field2 = $("#fieldID2");

    $type.change(function() {

        var isDisabled = ($type.filter(":checked").val() === "1");

        $field1.prop("disabled", !isDisabled);
        $field2.prop("disabled", isDisabled);

    }).change();
});
</script>
</head>
```

My html body is like:

```
<body>

<form action="" method="post">

<input type="radio" name="select" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="fieldID1" id="fieldID1"/>

<input type="radio" name="select" value="2" />
<table id="fieldID2">
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    ...
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
</body>
```

I referenced the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036635/improving-use-of-radio-buttons-to-enable-disable-form-fields). Can anyone point me out what the problem is, I am not quite familiar with jQuery, thanks!

Still cannot be fixed...

Comment: You have to select by name: `input[name="select"]`.

Comment: Its the same thing as just using $('select'), I tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $fieldID1.prop("disabled", !isDisabled);
    $fieldID2.prop("disabled", isDisabled);
```

Should probably be:

```
    $field1.prop("disabled", !isDisabled);
    $field2.prop("disabled", isDisabled);
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, its a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $type = $(':radio[name="select"]'),
        $field1 = $("#fieldID1"),
        $field2 = $("#fieldID2");

    $type.change(function() {

        var isDisabled = ($type.filter(":checked").val() === "1");

        $field1.prop("disabled", !isDisabled);
        $field2.prop("disabled", isDisabled);

    }).change();
});
```

Comment: change of definition of $type does not make any difference~

Comment: What browser are you using and what errors are you seeing in jsfiddle?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3973/discussion-between-michael-and-amit-g)